# What's the most performant way to replace a string from HttpContent and write it to HttpResponse?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a [HttpContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent?view=net-6.0) on the input.

I need to replace `example.com/thats-so-funny` with `example.com/thats-so-last-year` in the body and write it to a [HttpResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse). This is the way I am doing it right now:

```cs
var content = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var newContent = content.Replace("example.com/thats-so-funny", "example.com/thats-so-last-year");
await context.Response.WriteAsync(newContent, Encoding.UTF8);
```

I am looking to find a more performant way to do this - one that would continuously copy data from the input stream to the output stream - without loading the whole stream into memory.

Comment: `string.Replace("example.com/thats-so-funny", "example.com/thats-so-last-year").`

Comment: Faster in terms of programmer time or in terms of execution time?  How are you doing it now?

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews Faster in total execution time - the time from first read of the input until the last write to the output. I've clarified the question.

Comment: @Neil I've clarified the question.

Comment: string is a value type so it won't be possible since you already have a string and will have to get a copy of it in order to do anything with it. if you are creating the string from the start or doing the replace or other operations several times you could use the string builder for example but as the case you posted it there is no better way i believe.

Comment: @DSMSTHN HttpContent can be read in ways that don't create a `string`. `ReadAsStringAsync()` can be replaced with `LoadIntoBufferAsync()`, `ReadAsStreamAsync()` and others.